# Funny ASCI error with .replace("x","w")

Tags: python

I am making a program that takes a sentence and garbles it, until run through a "degarbler"

Theres probably a better way to do this, but I would appreciate it if everyone would show me how to fix what I am doing wrong

```
def sencoder (sentence):
    sentence = sentence.replace ("a","h")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("s","j")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("d","k")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("f","l")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("b","g")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("z","t")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("q","y")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("w","u")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("e","i")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("r","o")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("x","p")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("c","b")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("v","n")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("m","m")
    print sentence

def decoder (sentence):
    sentence = sentence.replace ("h","a")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("j","s")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("k","d")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("l","f")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("g","b")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("t","z")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("y","q")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("u","w")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("i","e")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("o","r")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("p","x")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("b","c")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("n","v")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("m","m")
    print sentence

sentence = ""
choice = raw_input ("Do you want to decode or encode: ").lower()   
while sentence != "quit":
    sentence = raw_input("Enter the code: ")
    if choice == "encode":
        decoder(sentence)
    elif choice == "decode":
        sencoder(sentence)
    else:
        print "Please make a valid decision"
```

help

Comment: What's the problem? What are you expecting?

Comment: Oh my eyes... Try `str.translate` or `re.sub` for such things.

Comment: How does the title match the code? I don't see replace("x","w") anywhere in the code...

Comment: Your encode option runs decoder and the decode option runs encoder. Is that by design? Normally the decode option runs the decoder and the encode option runs the encoder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a hint: Use the `translate` method instead.

```
>>> import string

>>> t = string.maketrans("abcdef", "bcdefa")
>>> "abracadabra".translate(t)
'bcrbdbebcrb'

>>> t2 = string.maketrans("bcdefa", "abcdef")
>>> "bcrbdbebcrb".translate(t2)
'abracadabra'
```

Comment: Thanks, at least you helped me solve the problem instead of "My eyes! Help, Oh god"

Answer (score 2):

> I am making a program that takes a sentence and garbles it, until run through a "degarbler"

Note that this will not work with any kind of input sentence:

```
encode ("ah") = "hh"   decode ("hh") = "aa"
```

If the two alphabets can overlap, you need to change your algorithm to keep partially-encoded data separate from the input string.

From your example it is not obvious if that is a problem, but I thought I'd better point it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your script "works for me."  Perhaps what is bothering you is that your meanings of encode and decode are switched?

That is, inputting "encode" invokes your decoder, and inputting "decode" invokes your encoder.

And as you see in the comments, please use `translate`! :)